# multiple memcached instance on single mysql?

Tags: mysql, memcached

Mysql supports Memcached plugin which is backed by innoDB engine. Following the doc it's easy to setup and run. It's good to development because you don't need to assign much memory for it.. But seems it's not mentioned in doc about how to setup multiple instance on multiple port. Is there any way to create multiple Memcached instance on a mysql instance? how to?

Comment: Assuming you are familiar with the `CONTAINERS` setup, I'm curious what problems multiple instances would solve.

Answer (score -1):

On 32-bit x86 systems where you are using PAE to access memory above the 4GB limit, you cannot allocate RAM beyond the maximum process size. You can get around this by running multiple instances of memcached, each listening on a different port:

```
shell> memcached -m 1024 -p11211
shell> memcached -m 1024 -p11212
shell> memcached -m 1024 -p11213
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my question is about Mysql's key-value interface. I'm looking for doc about setting multiple memcached instance / port * on mysql *. checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-memcached-setup.html about what I'm talking about.

Comment: Maybe you can try with multiple mysql instances that will run memcached separately